# "У меня пять самцов обезьян/обезьян-самцов/обезьян-особей мужского пола/обезьянних самцов"?

Tags: выбор-слова

I am really puzzled here. What's the right way to say in Russian "I have five male monkeys"?

Comment: All versions are correct, however the last one is more colloquial.

Comment: Yeah the last one makes sense the most

Comment: Почему пять..? :)

Comment: @Александр Подозреваю, чтобы в конце вышло "самцов" а не "самец" или "самца" ;-)

Comment: "У меня пять обезьян, и все самцы". :)

Comment: У меня пять мужиков, и все обезьяны :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer 'обезьян-самцов'. Other possible options:

- 'самцов обезьяны' - common (plural form of 'самец обезьяны')
- 'обезьян-особей мужского пола' - technically correct but not used

Incorrect options:

- 'обезьянних самцов' - obviously incorrect.
- 'самцов обезьян' - technically incorrect, sometimes used by mistake

Comment: I don't think that «самцов обезьян» is correct.